# Gremlin get Edge with specific start and end node

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I am using Gremlin to handle Titan Graph.
And I am trying to find a way to get a very specific relationship.

I have the label, the properties and a list of possible start and endNodes.

And I want all relationships matching this.

I have this already to get all relationships matching label and property:

```
GraphTraversal<Edge, Edge> tempOutput = g.E().hasLabel(relationshipStorage.getId());

            if(relationshipStorage.getProperties() != null)
            {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : relationshipStorage.getProperties().entrySet())
                {
                    if (tempOutput == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    tempOutput = tempOutput.has(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
```

But I didn't find a way to get it with a specific start and endNode.
I don't want to get multiple edges between two nodes.
I only want one edge with the specific vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Between Vertices](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#between-vertices) recipe and just extend from there. For example, let's say you wanted to find edges between two vertices with ids 1 and 2. Let's further assume you only wanted "knows" edges with a "weight" property greater than 0.0.

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(1).bothE().where(otherV().hasId(2)).hasLabel('knows').has('weight',gt(0.0))
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
gremlin> g.V(1,2).bothE().where(inV().has(id, within(2,3))).hasLabel('created')
==>e[9][1-created->3]
gremlin> vStarts = g.V(1,2).toList().toArray()
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
gremlin> vEnds = g.V(2,3).toList().toArray()
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.V(vStarts).bothE().where(inV().is(within(vEnds))).hasLabel('created')
==>e[9][1-created->3]
```

Comment: Is something like this possible:?

ArrayList<Vertex> nodeStartList =  getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getStartNode(), g);
        ArrayList<Vertex> nodeEndList =  getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getEndNode(), g);

        GraphTraversal<Edge, Edge> tempOutput = g.V(nodeStartList).bothE().where(g.V(nodeEndList)).hasLabel(relationshipStorage.getId());

Comment: sure - there's a model for that in the recipe. updated the answer a bit...

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do I get the inV and within in java?

Comment: despite my executing that in the gremlin console which is based on groovy those are all java compatible statements. for convenience the console statically imports the methods of `__` class which gives you `inV()` (anonymous traversal). and it statically imports the fields of the enum `P` which gives you `within`. Please see these docs for more information: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#static-imports